# Counting the number rows returned in Group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

The task was to group it by member_id and to filter it out, by selecting only the member_id where there is at least one slot booked. I expected the result as 30. But it's printing 30 member_id individually. What is I am doing wrong?

```
select
    count(*)
from
    cd.members as mem
    inner join cd.bookings as bks on mem.memid = bks.memid
group by
    mem.memid
having
    sum(slots) >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to subquery your current aggregation query and then select the count:

```
select count(*)
from
(
    select cd.memid
    from cd.members mem
    inner join cd.bookings as bks on mem.memid = bks.memid
    group by mem.memid
    having sum(slots) >= 1
) t;
```